# Python subprocess error: rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1407) [client=3.0.6]

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

I'm writing a Python automation script to upload files via rsync. Running this from Bash works

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av -e “/usr/bin/ssh -i $PATH_TO_SSH_IDENTITY_KEY” $SRC USER@HOSTNAME:/firstparam/secondparam
```

However, running from Python gives this error

```
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1407) [client=3.0.6]
```

This is the code in question calling rsync

```
cmd = ['/usr/bin/rsync', '-av', '-e', config.ssh_identity, src, config.host + ':/rootpath' + firstparam + '/' + secondparam]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
```

where

```
config.ssh_identity = ‘/usr/bin/ssh -i $PATH_TO_SSH_IDENTITY_KEY’
config.host = ‘USER@HOSTNAME’
```

What could have caused the error?

Comment: try to get `PATH_TO_SSH_IDENTITY_KEY` from `os.environ` first.

Comment: You probably want `shell=False` since you're passing an array of parameters and don't want any of them to be further split on spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. According to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/474178/host-key-verification-failed-rsync-connection-unexpectedly-closed) I was running the script as superuser and it didn't like that I wasn't who I said I was (ec2-user). So had to associate superuser as ec2-user